# помогите создать svg

Tags: android-studio, svg, ui, дизайн, ux

Нашел один Ui и заинтересовала идея с такими волнами, но при попытке создать их в AI ничего дельного не получилось(частично из-за градиента)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал подобное svg... теперь надо вставить в андроид студио, но выдает подобную ошибку `the specified asset could not be parsed`
код

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 316 304" style="enable-background:new 0 0 316 304;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
 .st1{opacity:0.48;fill:url(#SVGID_2_);}
</style>
<radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="45.8292" cy="45.2492" r="148.8855" fx="18.7235" fy="109.8004" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
 <stop  offset="0.519" style="stop-color:#FAA95F"/>
 <stop  offset="0.9944" style="stop-color:#F9675B"/>
</radialGradient>
<path class="st0" d="M0,292c0-18,0-53,0-256C0,23,0,0,0,0s22,0,27,0c72,0,218,0,256,0c0.64,0,17,0,20,0c1.08,0-0.05,1.78-3,10
 c-2.35,6.54-3.24,6.66-4,8c-0.96,1.71-0.62,2.37-7,9c-4.97,5.16-5.58,5.8-7,7c-2.75,2.32-5.25,3.95-7,5c-2.01,1.97-4.68,4.41-8,7
 c-2.01,1.57-7.26,3.87-13,7c-5.33,2.91-5.21,2.55-13,6c-9.05,4.01-8.45,2.75-16,6c-2.28,0.98-8.99,3.77-18,6
 c-4.12,1.02-5.32,1.3-17,4c-13,3-18.96,5.14-22,6c-9.95,2.81-10.83,1.57-23,6c-14.34,5.22-15.24,4.92-25,10
 c-7.33,3.81-7.89,4.05-15,8c-9,5-10,8-15,12c-7.2,5.76-8,7-21,23c-8.06,9.92-6.34,8.52-12,18c-6.08,10.19-9.14,18.96-13,30
 c-2.75,7.86-4.53,14.21-7,23c-2.4,8.56-3.61,12.84-5,19c-2.09,9.22-3,11.06-5,17c-1.31,3.88-1.05,5.21-4,13
 c-1.76,4.64-3.12,8.47-4,11c-2,4-3.97,6.29-5,8c-2.63,4.35-2.17,2.53-6,8c-0.92,1.32-2.91,2.96-5,4C1,292,0,292.1,0,292z"/>
<radialGradient id="SVGID_2_" cx="157.5079" cy="151.6649" r="154.616" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
 <stop  offset="0.519" style="stop-color:#FAA95F"/>
 <stop  offset="0.9944" style="stop-color:#F9675B"/>
</radialGradient>
<path class="st1" d="M0,303c0,1.2,5.15-1.07,9-3c6.99-3.5,10.94-8.58,12-10c1.8-2.42,3.2-5.61,6-12c1.83-4.17,3.05-7.43,4-10
 c2-5.39,3-8.08,4-12c1.17-4.58,0.78-4.73,2-9c1.21-4.22,1.8-4.82,3-9c1.18-4.1,1.04-5.03,2-9c1.26-5.23,1.66-6.64,3-12
 c2-8,2.94-8.97,5-16c1.88-6.42,3.98-10.76,7-17c1.08-2.22,2.59-6.21,12-22c8.7-14.59,10.19-15.69,12-18c4.12-5.25,7.74-8.81,12-13
 c5.14-5.05,9.49-9.33,16-14c6.24-4.47,11.36-7.09,19-11c3.38-1.73,8.63-4.41,15-7c8.86-3.6,14.97-5.02,27-8
 c18.23-4.52,27.34-6.77,35-9c14.45-4.2,25.2-8.18,30-10c14.53-5.52,24.86-10.48,28-12c6.62-3.21,13.55-6.37,22-12
 c9-6,13.19-10.55,17-15c6-7,8.36-12.11,9-14c1.56-4.63,2.87-8.89,3-11c0.28-4.65,1.07-7.99,1.01-8l-0.03,0C310,0,300.46,0,299,0
 C259,0,121,0,11,0C0,0,0,0,0,0S0,280,0,303z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Да я вот попробовал посмотреть ролики...вроде получилось

Comment: но к большому сожалению я не могу по какой-то причине вставить данное svg в андроид студио...

Comment: вот теперь плюс тебе ...так как решени ты пытался искать самостоятельно